# Laravel 8 Dynamic Dependent Input

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-8

it's been a while since I stuck in this problem. So I want to make a dynamic selection, when I select a nis (student_id) then the column nama (name) is filled with the student name.

Input form
[image: Input form]

Output i want
[image: output]

method create

```
public function create()
{
    return view('admin.counseling.create', [
        'title' => 'Tambah Bimbingan dan Konseling',
        'students' => Student::all()
    ]);
}
```

create_blade.php

```
                  <form action="/admin/counseling/store" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Nomor Induk Siswa</label>
                              <select name="nis" required class="form-control" id="nis">
                                <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-Pilih-</option>
                                @foreach($students as $student)
                                  <option value="{{$student->id}}">{{$student->nis}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                              </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Nama</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col text-right">
                            <button
                              type="submit"
                              class="btn btn-success px-5"
                            >
                              Simpan
                            </button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

I have watched and read some questions with similar problems, and yet I still didn't get it

**UPDATE**
My method in my controller

```
public function find_nis(Request $request)
{
    $data = Student::find($request->id); //Counseling::with('student', 'student.student_class')->where('student_id', $request->id)->first();
    return response()->json(['view' => view('admin.counseling.create', ['data' => $data])->render()]);
}
```

My Ajax in create.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function (){

      $(document).on('change','.student_nis',function () {

            var student_id = $(this).val();

            var a = $(this).parent();
            console.log(student_id);
            var op="";
            $.ajax({
              type      : 'GET',
              url       : '{!! URL::to('find_nis') !!}',
              data      : 'id=' + student_id,
              success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                a.find('.student_name').val(data.name);
              },
              error:function(){

              }
            });

        });

  });
</script>
```

My Route

```
Route::get('/admin/counseling/find_nis', [CounselingController::class, 'find_nis'])->name('find_nis');
```

this is output in my browser console when i select nis 1212
[image]

Comment: Have you tried handling this using Javascript on the frontend?

Comment: Can you share your "store" function as that is the one to return the value back to the view

Comment: @Charles i dont really understand with ajax/javascript thats why

Comment: If JS is not your strong suit, try to develop your form using livewire, and here is a tutorial dynamic form using livewire in bahasa https://codelapan.com/post/dynamic-form-laravel-8-livewire

Answer (score 0):

i think for getting response from DB without refresh page you should use ajax,
post student_id with ajax to Controller get username from DB and return your view like this:
in your blade:

> first you must set this meta tag inside of :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

> then config and post your data with ajax like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var studentId = $("input[name=student]").val();

                $.ajax({
                    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
                    type:'POST',
                    url:"{{ route('getStudentInfo') }}",
                    data:{studentId:studentId},
                    success:function(data){
                        $('html').html(data.view);
                    }
                });
</script>
```

> in your Controller inside of getStudentInfo():

```
$student = DB::table('user')->find($studen_id);
$username = $student->username;
return response()->json(['view' => view('admin.counseling.create', compact('username'))->render()]);
```

Comment: hello shahin, thank you for your response. the first thing i want to solve here is the dynamic dependent form. so if i select  in dropdown 'nomor induk siswa' (student id number) then in form 'nama' (name) should have value based on their student id number like in the second picture. and ya after that i want to save the data in to database. because like @Win says ajax is not my strong suit

Comment: Hello, @shanin I have updated my questions with my ajax, route, and method am i using. and it says "Not Found" in the console. I don't understand where the mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

Here the working solutions

*Route

```
Route::get('/admin/counseling/find_student', [CounselingController::class, 'find_nis'])->name('find_student');
```

*Controller

```
public function create()
{
    return view('admin.counseling.create', [
        'title' => 'Tambah Bimbingan dan Konseling',
        'students' => Student::all(),
        'problems' => Problem::all()
    ]);
}

public function find_nis(Request $request)
{
    $student = Student::with('student_class')->findOrFail($request->id);
    return response()->json($student);
}
```

*blade

```
<div class="container-fluid mt--7">
    <div class="mt-8">
        <div class="dashboard-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                  @if ($errors->any())
                      <div class="alert alert-danger">
                          <ul>
                              @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                  <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                              @endforeach
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                  @endif
                  <form action="/admin/counseling/store" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Nomor Induk Siswa</label>
                              <select name="nis" required class="form-control" id="nis">
                                <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-Pilih-</option>
                                @foreach($students as $student)
                                  <option value="{{$student->id}}">{{$student->nis}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                              </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Nama</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="student_name" id="student_name" disabled required/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Kelas</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="student_class_name" id="student_class" disabled required/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Permasalahan</label>
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                  @foreach ($problems as $problem)
                                  <div class="form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="" name="problem_name[]" value="{{ $problem->name }}">
                                    <label class="fs-6 fw-light">{{ $problem->name }}</label>
                                  </div>
                                  @endforeach
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Bobot Permasalahan</label>
                              <select name="priority" required class="form-control" id="nis">
                                <option value="null" disabled="true" selected="true">-Pilih-</option>
                                <option value="1">Normal</option>
                                <option value="3">Penting</option>
                                <option value="5">Sangat Penting</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col text-right">
                            <button
                              type="submit"
                              class="btn btn-success px-5"
                            >
                              Simpan
                            </button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

*ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function (){

      $(document).on('change', '#nis', function() {

            var student_id = $(this).val();

            var a = $('#student_name').parent();

            $.ajax({
              type      : 'GET',
              url       : '{{ route('find_student') }}',
              data      : 'id=' + student_id,
              success:function(data){
                a.find('#student_name').val(data.name);
              },

              error:function(){

              }
            });

      });

      $(document).on('change', '#nis', function() {

            var student_id = $(this).val();

            var a = $('#student_class').parent();

            $.ajax({
              type      : 'GET',
              url       : '{{ route('find_student') }}',
              data      : 'id=' + student_id,
              success:function(data){
                a.find('#student_class').val(data.student_class.name);
              },

              error:function(){

              }
            });

      });

  });
</script>
```